# S3Stream is getting closed before processing the entire payload

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-java-sdk

I am processing the bulk json payload from s3. 
code as follows:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3Object;
import static com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken;
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures;
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture;   

public boolean sync(Job job)
        throws IOException

//validating the json payload from s3.
try(InputStream s3Stream = readStreamFromS3()) 
{
    validationService.validate(s3Stream);
} 
catch (S3SdkInteractionException e) {
{ 
   logger.error(e.getLocalizedMessage();
}

//process the json payload from s3.
try (InputStream s3Stream = readStreamFromS3())
{
    syncService.process(s3Stream);
}
catch (S3SdkInteractionException e) {
{
    logger.error(e.getLocalizedMessage();
}
}


public InputSteam readStreamFromS3()
{
    return S3Object.getObjectContent();
}

// Process will sync the user data in the s3 stream. 
// I am not closing the stream till the entire stream is processed.  I 
// need to handle as a stream processing. 
// I dont want keep the contents in memory for processing, not 
   feasible for my use case.
public boolean process(InputStream s3Stream)
{
    jsonFactory = objectMapper.getFactory();   
    try(JsonParser jsonParser = jsonFactory.createParser(s3Stream) {

        JsonToken jsonToken = jsonParser.nextToken();
        List<HttpResponseFuture<UserResponse> userFutures = new ArrayLsit<>(20);
        while(true) {
           for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
              try {
                   // stream is processed fully
                    if (jsonToken == null || jsonToken == JSONTOKEN.END_OBJECT) { break; }

                   while (!jsonToken.isStructStart()) {
                           jsonToken = jsonParser.nextToken();    
                       }

                   // Fetch the user record from the stream
                   if (jsonTokenn.isStructStart()) {
                       Map<String,Object> userNode = jsonParser.readValueAs(Map.class);

                      // calling an external service and adding future response
                      userFutures.add(executeAsync(httpClient, userNode);

                    //Move to the next user record
                     if (jsonToken == JSONTOKEN.START_OBJECT) {
                           jsonToken = jsonParser.nextToken();     
                       }
                   }
                 }
              catch (JsonParseException jpe) {
                   logger.error(jpe.getLocalizedMessage());
                   break;
               }
             }

             for(ListenableFuture<UserResponse> responseFuture : Futures.inCompletionOrder(userFutures)) {
                 JsonResponse response = responseFuture.get();
            }

         } 

   }
   return false;
}
```

There is serviceA through which we are ingesting data (json payload) to S3. 
Another serviceB (the pseudocode shown above) will process the s3 data and call another serviceC to sync the data (json payload) in underlying store.

Problem:

I am seeing repeated s3 warning in our code. com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.S3AbortableInputStream               Not all bytes were read from the S3ObjectInputStream, aborting HTTP connection. This is likely an error and may result in sub-optimal behavior. Request only the bytes you need via a ranged GET or drain the input stream after use

The validation phase is executing as expected without any issues. 
However on syncing the data(ie. syncService.process()), the s3Stream is getting closed before the entire payload is processed. 
Since the stream is getting the closed before i process the entire stream, i am in inconsistent state.

Dependency information as follows

aws-java-sdk-s3:1.11.411

guava:guava-25.0-jre

jackson-core:2.9.6

Json payload could vary between few MB's to 2 GB.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you want people to help you, you need to help them. That starts with actual code, not "pseudocode" (it's not really pseudo-code, it's a bad copy-paste from your actual code). You also need to say what libraries you're using: there are dozens if not hundreds of JSON parsers in the world. And you need to include the _exact_ exception, _with stack trace_.

Comment: @kdgregory, Thanks for the feedback. I have added the code along with dependency information. I am not getting any exception to post stack trace. I am getting s3abortableinputstream warning on processing large payloads. The problem for me is that the underlying s3 stream is getting closed before i process the payload.

Comment: It's still not your real code ("ArrayLsit" won't compile). But what's happening is that you're not processing the entire file in `process()`, and the SDK warns you that there's still data that you haven't processed. So you need to figure out why that method is stopping early.

Comment: I am passing the input stream from S3 to process(), the sync() has try with resources which calls process(). I am expecting once the input stream is consumed by process(), the autocloseable in sync() would close the stream. However the stream is getting closed before the process() completely consumes the input stream.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't believe you. I see nothing in your code that would allow you to make that assertion, and I don't believe that streams get randomly closed. If you want to prove that the stream is being closed independently of the `try`, then do the following: after calling `process()`, log the value of `s3Stream.read()`. If the stream has been closed, this will throw an exception. If the stream has been fully consumed, it will return -1. If neither of those happen, then it means that you're not fully reading the stream, and need to figure out why.

Comment: And in case it wasn't obvious: call `read()` _within the try_.

Comment: It's also possible that the `JsonParser` is closing the stream, since you have it in a try-with-resources. However, since this is clearly not your real code, I can't tell you where to put the test. Wherever you actually break out of the loop.