# How to download and process large S3 file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-java-sdk

I have a large JSON file (i.e 100MB to 3GB) in S3. How to process this? 
Today, I am using `s3client.getObjectContent()` to get the input stream and trying to process.

As I stream it, I am passing the `inputstream` to Jackson jsonparser and fetching each JSON object and calling another microservice to process the JSON object retrieved from the s3 input stream.

Problem:

As I am processing the JSON object, S3 stream is getting closed without processing the entire payload from S3.

I am getting warning:

> S3AbortableInputStream:Not all bytes were read from the S3ObjectInputStream, aborting HTTP connection

I am looking for a way to handle large S3 payload without the S3 client closing the stream before I process the entire payload. Any best practices or insights are appreciated.

**Constraints:** I need to process this as a stream or with a minimal memory footprint.

Comment: Have you considered downloading the whole file first, then processing it locally?

Comment: Is there an actual problem with the processing, or are you just getting the warning? In lots of the cases this warning can be safely ignored, it just means that that one HTTP connection can't be reused. There are many reasons the stream might get closed with bytes left in it, for example getting an object to in order to check metadata to determine whether or not to pull it from a cache. It might help to share the code where you are interacting with the stream.

Comment: Why are you storing up to 3GB in a JSON file? That seems like a problematic design. I don't know the shape of your data but maybe you would you be better off storing the items in an actual database (e.g. MongoDB or DynamoDB)?

Comment: Asking the same question with less information than [your previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55227573/s3stream-is-getting-closed-before-processing-the-entire-payload) isn't going to get you any better answers. _You need to debug_ why _you're_ not reading the entire stream.

Comment: @jarmod, from cost-optimisation point of view, storing large data which doesn't change and needs to be fetched frequently in s3 is the best bet. No wonder why we can't do Dynamodb. But this would be better option only if the data changes/gets updated frequently and needs to be queried.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please make the following change in your code and check?

FROM:

```
if (s3ObjectInputStream != null) {
                s3ObjectInputStream.abort();
            }
```

TO:

```
if (s3ObjectInputStream == null) {
                s3ObjectInputStream.abort();
            }
```

Comment: I don't think is what you want to do. This would consistently throw a NullPointerException.